# Git format-patch issue

Tags: git

I have a local branch in git that I use to develop. From that branch I want to create a patch to the main branch, present both locally and remotely.
I tried to create the patch using git format-patch

```
git format-patch <baseline branch>
```

but instead of showing me the latest changes it is using a previous commit to create the patch. It is the first time this happens to me, since I had used this command several times.
Now, if I use git diff, the changes are shown correctly:

```
git diff <baseline branch>
```

I tried creating a new branch from the baseline, merging my development branch into it and then perform the patch creation process, but same result. 
I also tried specifying the commit hash explicitly when creating the patch.
I even clean up the git cache and then tried to create the patch, with same result.

Any hint?

Comment: Were your changes actually committed or were they just changes in your working tree? `format-patch` is for creating a patch file which contains the differences between existing commits. `diff` shows changes against your working tree (and this diff can be formatted as a patch).

Comment: I commit all the changes. If I do a git status it mentions that there is nothing to commit.

Comment: BTW If I create a new branch, and copy the files manually, commit and then create the patch, it works ok.